# Solve $|x+1|+|x+2|+ ...+ |x+2019|=x^2+2019x-2020, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve
$$|x+1|+|x+2|+ ...+ |x+2019|=x^2+2019x-2020, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

It is obvious that:
$x^2+2019x-2020\geq \frac{2019 \cdot 2020}{2}$

I tried: $x\in [-\infty,-2019], x\in [-2019,-1]$ and $x\in [-1, \infty]$ but I didn't obtain a beautiful result.

I tried many values for $x$, but I can't find the correct one.
Can somebody give me an idea? Thank you!

Comment: If $x\ge -1, x=\sqrt{2041210}$ and if $x\le -2019, x=-3447$

Comment: One thing to try is to assume $x\geq 0$ such that all the absolute values can be removed.

Answer (score 3):

First assume $x\leq -1$. Let’s say $a\leq 2019$ with $a\in\{1,\ldots,2019\}$ maximal so that $x+a\leq0$. Then you want to solve
$$ -ax - a(a+1) + (2019-a)x + 2019\cdot 2020/2 = x^2 + 2019x -2020$$
that is
$$ x^2 + (2019+2a-2019)x - 2041210 - a(a+1) = x^2 + 2ax - 2041210 - a(a+1) = 0 $$
This gives
$$ x_{1,2}=-a \pm \sqrt{a^2 + 2041210 + a(a+1)} $$
where the solution needs to be in $[-a-1,-a]$ (or $(-\infty,-2019]$ for $a=2019$). Thus the positive root is not possible. For the negative one:
$$ a^2 + 2041210 + a(a+1) = 2a^2 + 2041210 + a$$
This is clearly always larger than $1$. So a solution only exists for $a=2019$ (i.e. $x\leq -2019$) where we get
$$ x=-\sqrt{2039191} - 2019 $$

All that remains is $x>-1$. Here we simply need to solve
$$ 2019\cdot 1010 + 2019x = x^2+2019x-2020$$
which gives
$$ x= \sqrt{2041210}$$

So we get two solutions $x=-\sqrt{2039191} - 2019$ and $x=\sqrt{2041210}$.

Comment: Note the formula $-ax-a(a+1) + (2019-a)x + 2019\cdot 1010$ has no $/2$ for the $a(a+1)$ because we’ve added these too much in $2019\cdot 1010$, so we need to subtract them a second time, i.e.
$$ -ax-a(a+1)/2 + (2019-a)x + 2019\cdot 1010 - a(a+1)/2$$

Answer (score 2):

Can't be posted as a comment, so please don't downvote.

Here are the graphs of the two sides of the equation:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The values were ugly, and I thought maybe something was wrong!

Answer (score 2):

The equation can be written as
$$|x+1|+|x+2|+ ...+ |x+2019|=(x+2020)(x-1)$$
Since the left hand side is positive, also $RHS>0.$ Thus $x>1$ or $x<2020.$ The approach is analogous for both cases, hence **I will do it for $x>1.$**

$LHS$ is the sum of distances from $x$ (represented by a point on $x-$axis) to $-1,-2,\dots,-2019,$ and is equal to $$x+1+x+2+\dots+x+2019=2019x+2019\times1010.$$ Now, solve $$2019x+2019\times1010=x^2+2019x-2020,$$ which gives $$x=\sqrt{1010\times 2021}\approx1428.7092,$$ because $x>1.$